# Heisenbug in IE9

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

Okay StackOverflow - this is a weird one.

**The Problem**

So I have a "button" (really just a div with a javascript onclick listener) that gets its text from a database via json on page load. (It makes sense given the application). We are not supporting IE < 9.

The problem is that the text inside the div does not show up in a fresh instance of IE9. HOWEVER, when I open up the developer console (to try to figure out what went wrong) and refresh the page, IE acts as though nothing ever went wrong and populates the button text correctly. It works in every other browser.

What.

**The Code**

So here's what I have in PHP:

```
<div class="dark-button notification-button" data-notification="NOTIF_A">
    <span class="float-right">&#9654;</span>
</div>
```

Javascript (using Jquery 1.8.0):

```
$('document').ready(refreshNotificationButtons('.notification-button'));
function refreshNotificationButtons(buttons){
    var buttons = typeof buttons != 'object' ? $('.notification-button') : buttons;
    var allNotifications = {};
    var buttonsCount = 0;
    buttons.each(function(){
        var button = $(this);
        if(typeof button.attr('id') == 'undefined') button.attr('id', 'notif-button-' + buttonsCount);
        buttonsCount ++;
        if(typeof allNotifications[button.attr('data-notification')] == 'undefined'){
            allNotifications[button.attr('data-notification')] = [button.attr('id')];
        } else {
            allNotifications[button.attr('data-notification')].push(button.attr('id'))
        }
    });
    $.get(
        '/notifications/get_notifications/' + $.map(allNotifications, function(x, abbr){return abbr}).join(','),
        '',
        function(data){
            $(data).each(function(){
                if (typeof allNotifications[this.Notification.NotificationAbbr] != 'undefined'){
                    console.log(this); //debug
                    buttonEl = $('#' + allNotifications[this.Notification.NotificationAbbr]);
                    if(this.Notifications_User.UserID != null) buttonEl.addClass('notification-button-remove');
                    buttonEl.attr('data-notification-id', this.Notification.Notifications_TableID);
                    buttonEl.append($('<span class="notification-button-signup-span">' + this.Notification.EnableText + '</span><span class="notification-button-remove-span">' + this.Notification.DisableText + '</span>'));
                }
            });
        },
        'json'
    );
```

}

**Images**

Button before opening dev console:

[image: Button before opening dev console]

Button after opening dev console and refreshing:

[image: Button after opening dev console]

**Conclusion**

Any ideas? I'd be happy to post more code if you would like to see it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove your `console.log()`'s, or add in this plugin: http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/

Comment: Oh, hm - you're thinking it's dying when there's no console object to log to? I'll try that.

Comment: Yup, that did it. If you want to write it up as an answer I'll gladly give you the rep you deserve.

Comment: It is truly a heisenbug.  The act of trying to debug caused the bug :)

Comment: I have to admit it, I smiled when I read "HOWEVER, when I open up the developer console", I bet most people reading your question did too :)

Comment: Just an aside: don't use clickable divs unless you don't care about people who can't or don't use a mouse or other pointing device. You should use an anchor tag (which of course you can style as you see fit) so that the link is accessible via the keyboard.

Comment: It's a Heisenburg!, Breaking Bad anyone?

Comment: @nnnnnn oh good point! I hadn't thought of that. I'll make a note of that in our system right now to get those changed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented above, `console.log()` doesn't work so well in IE when there is no console open to write to.

You can either remove the calls to `console`, or add in this plugin (developed by Paul Irish)

http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/

Comment: The statement `debugger` has a similar behaviour in IE, btw. You can only comment those out, since `debugger` is neither a function nor an object in itself and thus cannot be wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

IE only has a `console` object when the debugger is active.

So, when you try to do `console.log()` and there is no `console` object, it throws a javascript exception as it tries to reference the `.log` property of `undefined` and your code stops executing.

You can work around that by inserting this in your initialization code - somewhere before you use `console.log()`.

```
var console = console || {};
if (!console.log) {
    console.log = function(data) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

This just makes it safe to always use `console.log()`, even in IE when the debugger isn't running.  I wouldn't recommend leaving `console.log()` statements in finished production code, but it might help you during development.